# Is there a function in PHP or codeigniter to make back button (button to go to previous URL)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm using php and codeigniter. Is there a function in PHP or codeigniter to make back button (button to go to previous URL)?

Please help

Comment: No you can't do this in PHP. You could technically... but it would all happen before the page was rendered for the user. What you want is JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

```
<a href = "<?=$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]?>">Back </a>
```

**Javascript**

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Could use the header() function, If you want to go back to a previous URL without the user clicking it. There is no function given in COdeIgniter, but you can use the native PHP function header().

```
public function something()
{
  ....

   if($someThingFailed == "true")
     header('location: '. $_SERVER["HTTP_REFFERER"]);
  else
  {
     ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript - `document.referrer` - is what you are looking for